# sed does not match the regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I've wrote [this](http://regexr.com/3cvdf) regex:

```
/_([^_+\n][\w]+)_/g
```

and I wanted to test it out on my terminal with

```
echo "HELLO ___ _HELO_WORLD_" | sed "/_([^_+\n][\w]+)_/g"
```

However, it outputs

```
HELLO ___ _HELO_WORLD_
```

which means sed does not match anything.

The result needs to be :

```
_HELLO_WORLD_
```

I am using OS X, and I tried both `-E` and `-e` as suggested by other posts, but that didn't change anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What means "filter"? Search or remove?

Comment: https://regex101.com/ nice User name.

Comment: (1) The `g` command will just copy the pattern space to the hold space, it will not modify the input. (2) sed is using basix posix regular expressions, looks like you are trying perl compatible regexes, which won't work. Your question shows that you did not read the manual of `sed`, do it!

Comment: @ceving Sorry about the confusion. I mean match. Remove everything that doesn't match a pattern.

Comment: @hek2mgl Apparently not enough. I've been reading regex related materials past several hours, yet I barely grasped on how to build regex pattern, nevermind POSIX vs. PERL.

Comment: @hek2mgl I thought `g` meant `global`? It's not going to modify the input, but wouldn't it match the pattern?

Comment: @abasu I've tried the same pattern on regex101.com with more tests, but it seem to output the same results, so I think pattern itself is good.

Comment: What would you like to match? `echo "HELLO ___ _HELO_WORLD_" | sed -e "s/.*_\([_\w]\)_/\1/g"`?

Comment: @frbl Isn't output of that  `_ _HELO_WORLD_`? I just need `_HELLO_WORLD_`

Comment: You need to escape the brackets... and the `+` and also to use substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is not particularily well suited for this task, as it really is good at applying patterns to lines, less so to words, making the regexes overly complicated.

#### word-oriented solution

anyhow, here's an attempt, using two replacement patterns:

```
sed -e 's|\<[^_][^\> ]*[^_]\> *||g' -e 's|\<_*\> *||g'
```

the first expression replaces any word that is neither starting nor ending with underscores (and any trailing whitespace) by nought. `\<` indicates the beginning of a word, and `\>` the ending; so `\<\([^_][^\>]*[^_]\)\>` translates to "at the beginning `\<` there is no underscore `[^_]`, followed by any number of characters not ending the word `[^\>]`. followed by a character that is not an underscore `[^_]` right before the word ends `\>`

the second expression is simpler and replaces any word solely consisting of underscores with nought.

#### line oriented processing

if you can arrange for your data to be one expression per line you can use something like the following

```
$ cat data.txt
HELLO
___
_HELO_WORLD_
$ cat data.txt | sed -n -e '/_[^_+\s]\w*_/p'
_HELO_WORLD_
$
```

The sed-term is almost the one you gave (though for some reasons `sed` doesn't like the `+`, so I use a workaround with `*` instead.

The basic trick is to use the `-n` flag to disable the default printing of lines and to use the `p` command to explicitely *print* matching lines.

Comment: Use `\{1,\}` for `+` in [basic regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03).

Comment: You need to escape the `+` unless you are using extended regex i.e `-r/-E` flag.Also this will only match the last occurence of words enclosed in `_`'s although tbh I'm not actually sure what OP wants to achieve so it may be right.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what you are asking, so I answer what I guess you are asking. My guess is, that you want to find strings surrounded by underscores with Sed. The short answer is: no. The longer is: you can not find overlapping string parts with Sed, because it does not support [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

If you take this string `_HELLO_WORLD_` and the following pattern `_[^_]*_`, the pattern will match `_HELLO_` and the remaining string is `WORLD_`, which will not match, because the leading underscore has already been consumed.

Sed is the wrong tool for this. Use Perl instead. This prints all strings surrounded by underscores:

```
$ echo "HELLO ___ _HELO_WORLD_" | perl -ne 's/_([A-Z]+)(?=_)/print $1/ge'
HELOWORLD
```

Update reflecting your last comment:

If you want to find strings starting and ending with an underscore at [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), use this one:

```
$ echo "HELLO ___ _HELO_WORLD_" | perl -ne 's/\b_([A-Z]+[_A-Z]*[A-Z]*)_\b/print $1/ge'
HELO_WORLD
```

Comment: Hm.. Interesting. So is regexr using perl regex? Because [mine](http://regexr.com/3cvdf) seems to include two words separately by underscore as well.

Comment: Definitely can use sed.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problem :

- your sed command is a condition. It should be an action, as `s/pattern/replacement/flags` or the condition could be followed by an action, i.e. `/_([^_+\n][\w]+)_/p` to print the line.
- with sed, you either need to escape your parentheses and `+` or to use the `-r`regex-extended flag
- `[\w]` : `\w` is already a character class by itself, no need to encase it in a class

Finally, a shot at what I think you want with GNU grep :

```
grep -P -o "_[^_+\n\s]\w+_"
```

> ```
> $ echo "HELLO ___ _HELO_WORLD_" | grep -P -o "_[^_+\n\s]\w+_"
> _HELO_WORLD_
> ```

- Using grep is enough and easier if you only need to match.
- `-o` will able you to retrieve only the matched part rather than the whole line
- `-P` uses perl regexes so that you can use shorthand classes as `\n` and `\s`
- I added `\s` to the negated class, because previously it could match the space before what you want to match, since `\w` can match the underscore.

If you can't use GNU grep, then it's back to sed, which is already answered by ceving.

Comment: I used GNU grep yes ; anything not specified in POSIX?

Comment: Solaris does know neither `-P` nor `-o`. I am not sure about OSX.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check for a POSIX alternative

Comment: @Aaron There is none, gnu is the only one to include only outputting matches, although you could remove the P and just use basic regex.

Comment: @123 yeah indeed, back to sed if you don't have GNU grep

Answer (score 0):

As many answers and the downvotes suggest, `sed` doesn't look like the right tool to use for this question, so I ended up using Python, which worked out really well, so I will just post it here for anyone in the future who might have same problem.

```
import re
p = re.compile('_([^_+\n][\w ]+)_')
result = p.findall(text)
```